# Quantization converterError 2471 Check failed: status.ok()

Tags: python, tensorflow, quantization

Environment: tensorflow=2.0, tensorflow-model-optimization=0.3.0, python=3.6.8

when convert keras model to tflite through below code:

```
m1='ownmodel_pruW.h5'
model=tf.keras.models.load_model(m1)
tflite_model_file = 'ownnet.tflite'
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
with open(tflite_model_file, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(tflite_model)
```

error as below

***ConverterError: See console for info.
2020-05-14 20:43:12.220536: F tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:2471] Check failed: status.ok() Neither input_content (0) nor float_val (73723) have the right dimensions (73728) for this float tensor
(while processing node 'Modelnet/conv2/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp')***

Any method to solve this error?

Comment: Hi it seems like you have an undefined shape in your model. Can you try the newest version of Tensorflow (pip install tf-nightly) to see if this resolves your issue?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Tried different versions of tensorflow, results as below:

1. Tensorflow==1.13.1: 
works fine after adding code "converter.post_training_quantize = True"

Comment: 2. tensorflow==1.15:  
tf.lite.Interpreter: RuntimeError: Encountered unresolved custom op: FusedBatchNormV3.Node number 2 (FusedBatchNormV3) failed to prepare.

Comment: 3. Tensorflow-gpu==2.1/2.2 or Tensorflow==2.1/2.0:
ConverterError as shown in this topic.

Comment: 4. Tf-nightly==2.3:
(a lot of error) ...toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: FusedBatchNormV3
tooling_util.cc:627] Check failed: dim >= 1 (-1 vs. 1)

Comment: tf-nightly should be working even with the dim size issue. I guess you are not retraining your model with tf-nightly. Can you provide the model ownmodel_pruW.h5 -- it may be a mismatch between the training code and converter, or describe how you built it?

Comment: Many thanks for your answers. I trained the model, then pruned the model, finally convertered the model to tflite, but has this error. Please check my code here:
https://github.com/pkb14197/tensorflow-quantization-error-2471/blob/master/ownmodelPrune1.ipynb